# Adding column headers to a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as

```
{{100, 0.834189, 6.61855, 16.8056, 1.}, {101, 0.834123, 6.65273, 
  16.9009, 1.}, {102, 0.834059, 6.68675, 16.9957, 1.}, {103, 0.833995,
   6.7206, 17.0901, 1.}, {104, 0.833931, 6.7543, 17.184, 1.}, {105, 
  0.83387, 6.78782, 17.2775, 1.}, {106, 0.833809, 6.8212, 17.3706, 
  1.}, {107, 0.833746, 6.85442, 17.4633, 1.}, {108, 0.833685, 6.88749,
   17.5556, 1.}, {109, 0.833626, 6.92041, 17.6474, 1.}, {110, 
  0.833567, 6.95318, 17.7389, 1.}}
```

when I use `TableForm` command I get a table with 5 columns, Now I want to assign a name for each column so that it appears on top of the column, How can do so?
Suppose the name columns are: one, two, three, four, five

Comment: You want the `TableHeadings` option in `TableForm` or, for more flexibility, you can roll your own system using `Grid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `TableHeadings`might help :

```
data={{100, 0.834189, 6.61855, 16.8056, 1.}, {101,0.834123, 6.65273,16.9009, 1.}, {102, 0.834059, 6.68675, 16.9957, 1.},{103, 0.833995,6.7206, 17.0901, 1.}, {104,0.833931,6.7543,17.184,1.}, {105,0.83387, 6.78782, 17.2775, 1.}, {106,0.833809,6.8212,17.3706,1.}, {107, 0.833746, 6.85442, 17.4633, 1.}, {108,0.833685, 6.88749,17.5556, 1.}, {109, 0.833626, 6.92041, 17.6474, 1.},{110,0.833567, 6.95318, 17.7389, 1.}}
TableForm[data,TableHeadings -> {{}, {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that's ok

Comment: You are welcome